# Formatting Exponentials Without e or E

Tags: python

I have a list of the following type: `list = [1, 3, 4.23123e-07]`

I would like to write this list to a text file. I would like the file to look as follows:

```
1 
3
4.231-7
```

For the exponential term I would like to be able to rid myself of the `e` and any preceding zeros in the exponential itself so from `4.23123e-07` to `4.231-7`.

Is there any way to do this apart from looping through my list and placing in the string `4.231-7` in lieu of the integer `4.23123e-07`?

Comment: I am pretty sure `4.23123e-07` is not an integer...

Comment: Also, don't name variables `list` or you run the risk of overwriting the builtin `list` function.

Comment: If you need to put in line-breaks in SO's markdown, just leave a space at the end of the line. You don't need to make separate paragraphs.

Comment: My apologies! Thanks for the input

Comment: You should consider selecting an answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could remove any `e` from the string as well as any zeroes following a `+` or a `-`:

```
import re
values = [1, 3, 4.23123e-07]

def format_without_e(number):
  no_e = re.sub('e', '', str(number), re.IGNORECASE)
  return re.sub('(?<=[+-])0+', '', no_e)

formatted_numbers = [format_without_e(value) for value in values]

print(formatted_numbers)
# ['1', '3', '4.23123-7']

print("\n".join(formatted_numbers))
# 1
# 3
# 4.23123-7
```

Comment: You don't need to do two separate expressions for this, but it is much easier to read this way.

Comment: Thanks! This works well, but then my list become essentially one long string something like 134.23123-7. Is there any way to keep the elements of my list separate?

Comment: You should put newlines instead of spaces in the list. Instead of joining the strings, it would be better to use a list comprehension. Alternatively, you could join with a newline and enable cross-line substitution in your regex flags.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: The original question had spaces between values. updated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%g` for precision control and use `re` for simplify. Thanks @MadPhysicist for correcting the error.

```
import re

[re.sub('e([-+])?[0]*',r"\1", '%.4g'%s) for s in l]
```

For example

```
In [46]: l = [1, 3, 4.23123e-07]

In [47]: [re.sub('e([-+])?[0]*',r"\1", '%.4g'%s) for s in l]
Out[47]: ['1', '3', '4.231-7']
```

Comment: A list comprehension looks much nicer than `list(map(...`

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes! It is simpler, I'll edit it. Thks.

Comment: Also, your regex should be able to handle `[-+]?` after the `e`, not just a minus. So `'e([+-]?)[0]*',"-"`, substitute with `r'\1'`. With that change, I would say that this is the most Pythonic answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you consider more comprehensive. Thks

Comment: Thanks @MadPhysicist and danche